# Save a linked and embedded version on every save

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'd like to keep a working copy of my ai file, and also have a copy with images embedded so that I can easily share. Is there a setting in CC to create a embedded version of the file on every save?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, once you save as an embedded version, it stays as an embedded version, so all new imported assets get embedded when you save.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question fully, but can't you simply save your AI file (as your original/working copy), then export as a PDF when you want to share? Are you looking for a way to automate both? Have you looked into recording Actions?